# How can I categorize numerical columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table1, It has a column called employee number and I want to categorize it according to specific range
ex:

```
id  employeeNumber
1    0
1    50
2    100
3    500
4    1000
```

I want the result to be like this, for example if number of employees go from 
0 to 100 it will fall in C1,
500 to 1000 will fall in C2 .. etc

```
1  C1
1  C1
2  C1
3  C2
4  C2
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, not the skipped range nor dividing employeeNumber(?!) to ranges in the first place. In addition, if the ranges bounds are in a pattern (e.g. 100,200,300 or 10,100,1000) it implies a different solution.

Comment: And what is `etc...`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, and it will depend on how often you want to use the same groupings. If this is a one off, I'd suggest something like this (I'm not sure as your categories seem not to be continuous):

```
SELECT
    id,
    case
        when employeeNumber <= 100 then 'C1'
        when employeeNumber <= 500 then 'C2'
        /* etc, the first match will be used so no need to worry about missing '>='s */
        else 'Uncategorized' -- or if your final category has no upper limit, you could put that here, but be careful of `NULL`s as employeeNumber seems not to be a primary key field.
    end as Category
FROM
    Table1
```

If you want to reuse these categories then create a table as follows:

```
create table EmployeeCategories(
Category varchar(3), --Or whatever data type you need. You could also add extra columns to describe the category if that's helpful.
LowerBound int,
UpperBound int
)
```

Populate it with your groupings:

```
insert into EmployeeCategories
       (Category, LowerBound, UpperBound)
values ('C1', 0, 100),
       ('C2', 101, 1000)
       /* Etc */
```

For the final category you could leave the UpperBound `NULL` if there is no maximum. Then you do this:

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    ec.Category
FROM
    Table1 t
    CROSS JOIN EmployeeCategories ec
WHERE
    t.employeeNumber between ec.LowerBound and ec.UpperBound
    OR (t.employeeNumber >= ec.LowerBound and ec.UpperBound is null)
```

Comment: Adding `ELSE` to your first solution would make sense

Comment: Thanks @DuduMarkovitz, I've made an edit to include one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case`:

```
select t1.id,
       (case when employeenumber between 0 and 100 then 'C1'
             when employeenumber between 500 and 1000 then 'C2'
        end) as en_range
from table1 t1;
```

It seems strange that you don't have a range for 101-499.

Answer (score 2):

Use CASE statments like

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN employeeNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 100 THEN 'C1' 
    WHEN employeeNumber BETWEEN 101 AND 500 THEN 'C2' 
END as employeeCode FROM table
```